# Can I install debian-arm packages onto a debian sd-card using an x86_64 host system?

Tags: debian, dpkg, arm

I need to write a script which will install some arm debian packages onto a debian sd-card.  The script must run on an x86_64 debian desktop PC.

Can dpkg install packages, that are for a different architecture, onto a target filesystem?

What's the best way of doing this?  A chroot, or something else?

Comment: Can you explain why you want the x86 host do that instead of the ARM system itself?

Comment: @Philippos This is for continuous integration running on an x86_64 server.  It needs to be able to serve an up-to-date ARM SD card image, with the latest versions of in-house Debian packages installed.

Comment: Our CI provides `deb` packages to the ARM system, which is running as [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) client, executing the installation as part of the test setup. You can even use a build-in update mechanism of the system to test it at the same time. Anyhow, if that doesn't fit for you, you maybe want to use [ELBE](https://elbe-rfs.org/) or just copy their qemu-based mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Virtualbox, I'm quite sure chroot is out of the question:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/how-to-run-raspbian-on-virtualbox#1192